# @mui/icons-material/ShoppingCart not working in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using React 18.2.0.  And I am using @mui/icons-material/ShoppingCart , but it is not displaying shopping cart icon.

Code:

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import ShoppingCartIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ShoppingCart";

class Home extends Component{

  render(){
    return (
      <ShoppingCartIcon /> 
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

I have installed/updated all required dependencies. There is no error on console.
I installed using:

```
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
npm install @mui/icons-material
```

No shopping cart icon visible.

Comment: it is showing.
check it in www.codesandbox.io.
probably you have some configuration problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running commands "npm install" and then "npm ci", cleans and rebuild the project. And it works then.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code for your problem.

`
import React from "react";

import ShoppingCartIcon from "@mui/icon-material/ShoppingCart";

class Footer extends React.Component {

render(){

```
return <ShoppingCartIcon/>;
```

}

}

`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).